# Limit filetype and wp media - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, media, file-type

**This is my input markup:**

```
<div class="button-primary" id="fileToUpload">Upload</div>
```

**This is js:**

```
jQuery( '#fileToUpload' ).click( function()
{
    var custom_uploader = wp.media
    ({
        title: 'Select',
        button: {
            text: 'Select'
        },
        multiple: false  // Set this to true to allow multiple files to be selected.
    })
    .on( 'select', function()
    {
        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get( 'selection' ).first().toJSON();
        jQuery( '#previewImage' ).attr( 'src', attachment.url );
        jQuery( '.custom_media_url' ).val( attachment.url );
        jQuery( '.custom_media_id' ).val( attachment.id );
    })
    .open();
});
```

I want to limit the the file type to `jpg,jpeg and png`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to plug into the `upload_mimes` filter, like so:

```
function vnm_restrictMimeTypes($mimes) {
    $mimes = array(
        'jpg|jpeg|jpe' => 'image/jpeg',
        'png' => 'image/png',
    );

    return $mimes;
}

add_filter('upload_mimes','vnm_restrictMimeTypes');
```

This replaces the passed `$mimes` array with one limited to only the accepted image filetypes.

Note that this doesn't stop the user from *browsing* for non-allowed filetypes, but when they try to upload they'll receive an error: **Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.**

Comment: when this will display the error? when clicking on submit button of the form?

Comment: @HassanAli The error is displayed at the point the user tries to upload the disallowed filetype. Drop this into your `functions.php` file and give it a go. All your code does is replicate the standard **Add Media** functionality, so when you try to add a PDF or a GIF for example, you'll see the warning in a red box on the right of the Add Media dialog.